Send an email with multiple files as attachments in a single request using MS Graph
I create a API to send an email. I searched the web and found the example Microsoft.Graph send mail with attachment. However I have an error "The name 'MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage' does not exist in the current context". I already add the Microsoft.Graph (version 5.56) and Azure.Identity as reference.
The following code is from the above link:
// Create the message with attachment.
byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test\test.png");
string contentType = "image/png";
MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
{
    ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    ContentBytes = contentBytes,
    ContentType = contentType,
    ContentId = "testing",
    Name = "testing.png"
});
Message email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = Resource.Prop_Body + guid,
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    },
    Subject = Resource.Prop_Subject + guid.Substring(0, 8),
    ToRecipients = recipients,
    Attachments = attachments
};

// Send the message.
await graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync();

Would someone tell me what is the assembly file I need to add. Thanks

The example is for SDK v4, but you are referencing SDK v5.
For SDK v5 you can try the following code:
byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test\test.png");
string contentType = "image/png";
var attachments = new List<Attachment>
{
    new FileAttachment
    {
        ContentBytes = contentBytes,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentId = "testing",
        Name = "testing.png"
    }
};

var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            Content = Resource.Prop_Body + guid,
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        },
        Subject = Resource.Prop_Subject + guid.Substring(0, 8),
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "john.doe@contoso.com"
                }
            }
        },
        Attachments = attachments
    }
};
// Send the message.
await graphClient.Me.SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

As clarified, if your project is targeting .NET 4.8, you need to use SDK v4. The original code mentioned in the question should work.

2250152, thanks, The SendMailPostRequestBody is Miscrosoft Graph REST API v.1. My project  is target .NETframework  4.8.   When I install it, I got the error "Could not install package 'MicrosoftGraphManager.Core 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

@CDVS In that case, try to reference NuGet package Microsoft.Graph with version 4.54, the original code should work for v4
